# How to elegantly handle errors in methods using NSURLSessionTask with closures?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, swift2

I often have code like this, when I have a class that handles communication with a REST API, with a lot of methods inside that use NSURLSession tasks with closures as callbacks. I also give some of these methods callback closures so I can chain different API calls, one after another. I often call these methods out of a View Controller, for example as an action after pressing a button or in viewDidLoad.

Let's take an example class that talks to a imaginary API with one method that sends a POST request to register a new user with the API:

```
class ApiConnection {
    var session: NSURLSession!

    init() {
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        config.URLCache = NSURLCache.sharedURLCache()
        self.session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
    }


    func registerNewUser(user user: String, password: String, callback: (() -> Void)? ) {
        let data = ["email": user, "password": password]
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://backend.myapp.com/auth/register/")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        try! request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(data, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if (error != nil) {
                print("TODO do the right thing here for error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {

                do {
                    let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? NSDictionary

                    if httpResponse.statusCode == 201 {

                        print("registration went successfully")
                        callback?()

                    } else {

                        print("registration went wrong, not registered new user: \(result)")

                    }



                }
                catch {
                    print("TODO something went wrong decoding the JSON response")
                }
            }


        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

I can now, for example in a view controller, call this method with something like this:

```
let myAPI = ApiConnection()
myAPI.registerNewUser(user: "email@foo.bar", password: "testing") {
    // continue here, probably doing the next call
    print("user is registered")
}
```

So far so good, but this example totally lacks proper error handling ("TODO"s in the above code, in order to display warning dialoges or whatever. I am wondering how to improve my code to do this in an elegant way.

Of course, I could just give an error object back in the completion closure I have created, and do some `if error != nil` magic in the view controller, but that would be ugly and become cumbersome for consecutive calls.

I have thought that the new do-try-catch idiom could be perfect for this: having a completion closure that is only executed in a success case and beside of that a catch of a exception when anything went wrong, even with a nicely formatted error message that I could compose inside the APIConnection class. But after some reading I have found out it is not easily possible to throw out of a closure as this closure can be called at any time, even after the method itself is already executed, with makes sense to me but I have no idea how to nicely handle this kind of situations.

How are you experienced programmers handling this? Is my whole approach and architecture of my APIConnection class stupid and the whole thing can be done much more elegant? Plaese, any comment is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into using AFNetworking?

Comment: To be honest, not yet. How does AFNetworking solve that better? And should I use Alamofire instead of AFNetworking when working with Swift 2?

Comment: I would suggest to utilise a "Futures and Promises" library like [BrightFutures](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures) or [FutureLib](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/FutureLib).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What suits best for this kind of problems, is the `promises` concept. The actions that you perform in your code can easily be considered as piped actions: get_server_respose | parse_json | execute_callback. In a synchronous approach this would be very simple to write and will provide clean/readable code. In an asynchronous world, things get complicated, and you can easily get lost in the [callback hell](https://blog.cristik.com/2015/03/promises-and-objectivec-no-more-callback-hell/).

With promises, you can chain async operations in a very similar way you would pipe the synchronous versions, and you can have only one failure point, at the end of the chain.

Here's how a `promise`-d version of your problem could look:

```
let task =  session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
task.promisify.then({response, data in        
    guard let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse else {
       return failedPromise(Error(...)}
    }
    guard response.statusCode == 201 else {
       return failedPromise(Error(...)}
    }
    return jsonParsePromise(data);
}).then({ parsedDict in
    print("Registration went successfully")
    callback?()
}).then(nil, { error in
    print("An error occured: \(error)")
})
task.resume()
```

Much cleaner, with tasks like json parsing in a separate (testable) unit, and with only one failure point.

P.S. You can go even further and promisify the `registerNewUser` function itself:

```
func registerNewUser(user user: String, password: String) -> Promise {
    //... task setup
    return task.promisify.then({response, data in        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse else {
           return failedPromise(Error(...)}
        }
        guard response.statusCode == 201 else {
           return failedPromise(Error(...)}
        }
        return jsonParsePromise(data);
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

, which can be easily used by clients of the function:

```
registerNewUser(usernameTextfield.text, passwordTextfied.text).then({user in
    print("Registration succeeded with user \(user)")
}, {error in
    print("Registration failed with error \(error)")
})
```

Comment: Are you using PromiseKit for the above examples? I really think the concept of Promises make a lot of sense and I want to learn using it, therefore I would like to know which framework you recommend for Swift2.

Comment: I'm currently using one of my own frameworks, CKPromise. It's written in Objective-C with support from being called from Swift, and I'm planning to rewrite it in Swift. If you want to learn more about promises, you can also read my blog entries from [here](https://blog.cristik.com/2015/03/promises-and-objectivec-no-more-callback-hell/)

Comment: After looking around a bit, I have now solved my issues by using PromiseKit. It's not perfectly documented with Swift 2 but works very well and makes programming all kind of async stuff really easy. I have by the way also changed all my HTTP requests to use Alamofire and SwiftyJSON. Really nice combination.